# Most efficient way to SQL query table to return most common value found across multiple columns?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

My table is set up as such:

```
party_no   mdl     mfr_cd   asset_id
------------------------------------
013        FA85    DOG      VR67
666        389     POO      9AP
185        CAT     CAT      V7SZ
267        DOG     DOG      87NO 
389        555SUP  DOG      YES
666        DOG     DOG      DOG
185        S08     CAT      83NO
666        DOG     DOG      DOG
```

I am trying to find **the value that is most common amongst all columns** but it should not have to be in all 3 columns, but should be >1 column

That is, I would like to find the most common value across all the three columns (mdl, mfr_cd, asset_id) that appears the most frequent for a unique party_no.

So the above data would return something like this:

```
party_no   value   count 
------------------------
666        DOG      2
267        DOG      1
185        CAT      1
```

Ideally, values that appear in more columns, like "DOG" appearing in 3 columns 2 times, versus "DOG" appearing in 2 columns 3 times, should rank higher.

I was doing this:

```
select party_no, count(*)
from assets.asset_latest al
where mfr_cd = slsmdl_and_mdfy_no or mfr_cd = ser_no or mfr_cd = equip_asset_alt_nm or slsmdl_and_mdfy_no = ser_no or slsmdl_and_mdfy_no = equip_asset_alt_nm or ser_no = equip_asset_alt_nm
group by party_no
order by count(*) desc
```

It definitely sorts in order for the party numbers that have values matching across columns, but it doesn't rank if the value appeared in 3 columns vs. 2 columns like I stated above. Also, the multiple "=" statements in the where clause don't seem too efficient, because if I had more columns the combinations would get insane.

I'll take any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `lateral join` and `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (al.party_no) al.party_no, v.value
from assets.asset_latest al cross join lateral
     (values (al.mdl), (al.mfr_cd), (al.asset_id)
     ) v(value)
group by al.party_no, v.value
order by al.party_no, count(*) desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5f0617c8c625419ae5e404b3ec8eb19b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Well, I love how every SQL response on stack overflow with aliases never works in PostgreSQL (for me at least). Maybe its because I only sleep like 2 hours, but I'm really starting to hate SQL.

Comment: @ennth . . . I added a db<>fiddle and fixed a typo.

Comment: No problem I appreciate your help. I'm going to look into cross lateral joins, I suck and need to get better and hone my skills but I thank you for providing me base to start with :D